# Check my work in progress (Graviii game)

Tags: design, games, video-games, game

Hello again all fellow sound designers!

I post this to present to you my latest work in progress. Its in the form of a game by my team Tsimpountiii Games. We submitted our latest game GRAViii at kongregate.com for games made with Unity3D games.

You can find the game here http://www.kongregate.com/games/tsimpountiii/graviii . Please play the game and vote for it if you like it (that is going to be a great help for us!).

I used Logic 9 to produce the music and sound effects that you hear in the game and we are going to update the game regularly (next update coming tommorow 99% with more music / effects / levels and bug fixes). I used some recordings i did with my Sony PCM 50, of sea, some streams, and water drips!

Please leave me some feedback whether you like it or not! Or any ideas you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty cool. Just a quick run just before work.

Few things from the game design point of view -> you might want to consider pop-up instructions BEFORE the gameplay starts, it was kinda annoying trying to read the instructions while my orb was being sucked by a red one heh. And also, some kind of menu button would be useful, just to reset the level if you get stuck.

I'll get back onto this later on today. Really reminds me of osmos. In a good way!

Ok, so after a revisit, here are some things that i noticed:

- the game should progress normally from zone to zone. instead i was stuck in a loop fro a couple of levels not even realising haha ;)
- maybe you can think of some complete/fail short music sting?
- don't have a clue about how this engine works, but here is an idea: is it possible to put in a couple of tracks choosen on random? i mean, for example; each time you restart the level you have a bank of 5/6 different music tracks for the engine to start the level with. this decreases the 'annoying-repetitiveness' of the game. at the same time increasing gameplay and addictiveness.
- the 'loading'screen is kinda blurry. is that supposed to give an 'underwater' effect? not sure how i feel about it.
- at first i thought that i would like to hear more sound design for the 'evil-bubbles', but then i changed my mind. in some moments of the game it could just create noise.

Overall -> I love the game. great time waster ;) will definitely get it once you've released it on iOS.

Good luck with the project!

Comment: thank you for your feedback S_Mich. its really helpfull. we are now in the process of transfering everything for iOS devices and we kinda work like crazy. the thing about the ingame tutorial needs heavy work fixing... and i am happy that many players thought of Osmos cause i think its a good game!

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick go at it... very nice game

Comment: thanks Rishi, this game finaly helped us close a big deal with a very very big publisher and in the coming month you are going to see it in its next version and all the iDevices as well :) more coming soon!